# DynamoDB remap list attribute item on query

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to transform the output of a DynamoDB query (using doc-client in Lambda) during the query process. Specifically, I wish to extract the first item of a list and put it in a new attribute.

As a simplified example the DynamoDB has the following entries:

```
{
    "Id": 1
    "Items": [ "item-1", "item-2", "item-3" ]
},
{
    "Id": 2,
    "Items": [ "item-x" ]
},
{
    "Id": 3,
    // "Items" is potentially optional
}
```

And using the following Lambda function:

```
// ...

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return dynamoDoc.query({
        TableName                 : 'some-table',
        Select                    : 'SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES',
        KeyConditionExpression    : 'Id = :id',
        ExpressionAttributeValues : {
            ':id' : event.Id,
        },
        ProjectionExpression : `
            Id,
            Items[0]
        `,
    }).promise();
};
```

However this returns a list with items which look like:

```
"Items": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Items": [
            "item-1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Items": [
            "item-x"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": 3
    }
]
```

Is there a way to remap attribute names using some kind of expression, such that I could get the data output in the form of:

```
Items: [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "FirstItem: "item-1"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "FirstItem: "item-x"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3
    }
]
```

I am currently using Javascript's array.forEach on the data afterward, however, I am trying to avoid this and would rather leverage DynamoDB for this computation.

Answer (score 1):

No way.

Best practice is just create a helper function like a `Repository`, the helper function will wrap all query to Dynamodb and returns `final` object for handler function.

Quick fix, use `.map` instead of `.forEach`

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const result = await dynamoDoc.query({
    TableName: 'some-table',
    Select: 'SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'Id = :id',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':id': event.Id,
    },
    ProjectionExpression: `
            Id,
            Items[0]
        `,
  }).promise();

  result.Items = result.Items.map((i) => {
    return {
      Id: i.Id,
      FirstItem: i.Items && i.Items.length ? i.Items[0] : undefined,
    }
  });

  return result; // final result
};
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, a .forEach would still be better (than .map) because it doesn't recreate the full result structure again (object creation can add up in per-ms billing)? Though, I suppose I'll look at making a wrapper.